# How can I export a DBGrid to OOXML format (Excel 2007/2010 format) without Excel installed?

Tags: xml, delphi, excel, delphi-2007, openxml

I have a Delphi 2007 DBGrid that I'd like to allow the user to save in the newer Excel format ([OOXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)), but my criteria is that the user does not need to have Excel installed. Is anyone aware of any components that already do this? And yes, I did search already, but I have not found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the top of my head was [TMS FlexCel Studio for VCL](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcel.asp), but I was wrong. The current VCL version doesn't support xslx.  Their [.NET edition](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) does support xslx, though...

So a [quick google search](http://google.com/?q=delphi%20xlsx) pointed me to [an EDN discussion](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=6603) that refers to these sites:

- http://scalabium.com/
- http://www.nika-soft.com/

I have no knowledge about these products, but it might be worth a look...

Comment: I tried the last free and open-source version of FlexCel, v2.5.3, and it did not support creating OOXML compliant files. I downloaded it here: ftp://shamir.crysys.hit.bme.hu/pub/dsp/ftp/d50free/flexcel.zip

Comment: Ok, my mistake.  It's their .NET edition that supports xslx: http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp

Comment: I'd be very interested in any native Delphi component that could output OOXML formats

Comment: @David: I agree, hence the up-voting of the question.  I could swear that TMS supported ooxml, but I was obviously wrong...  NikaSoft's NativeExcel and Scalabium's TSMExportToXLSX seems to support this, so I'm going to have a closer look at these some day.

Answer (score 0):

Look at NativeExcel v3 from [NikaSoft](http://www.nika-soft.com/index.htm).   It claims to support XLSX format.

I have v2 which only supports XLS format.  It provides classes that mimic the Excel object model (sufficient for my needs) and includes components that export TDBGrid and TDataset.  I have used it with D7, D2007, and DXE.