# How to export multiple TdxDBGrid into an Excel worksheet?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-2007

In our application we are having different grids in a form having individual Export to Excel functionality. DevExpress [do not](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q442789) provide the functionality to Export multiple grids into an Excel worksheet.  How this can be done in Delphi 2007?

Thanks!

Comment: We had to create our own code to export multilevel grids (at least in our devExpress version it was not possible yet). Basically you would have to move through the `Views` you need to export and use `OLE` or some other alternative (not sure if D2007 has native export to Excel) to export the data to the different pages of your worksheet.

Comment: Search how to export data from Delphi to Excel - there are a lot of libraries, commercial and free, and there are a lot of articles about using Delphi's COM-based TExcelApplcation component

Comment: You say you have code to export one grid into Excel. What seems to be the problem, what stops you from running it on multiple grids one-by-one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+export+excel

- [Exporting data from a DBGrid to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058563)
- [Exporting grid to excel + OOXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105812) mentions TdxDBGrid
- [Exporting to excel from Delphi without having excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493071)
- [How can I export a DBGrid to OOXML format (Excel 2007/2010 format) without Excel installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765226)
- [ADO with XLSX files in Delphi XE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344467)
- [Copy TDataSet to XLS via ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682731)

You can start with either of those approaches and make your export routines. 1st of all you would have to decide whether you would place your different grids onto different sheets within the workbook, or into different files, or left to right in the same worksheet.

Maybe most lazy approach would be to export them to different worksheets, and after that using Excel's COM server (via Delphi `TExcelApplication` component) to move those sheets into one main workbook, and then close and delete all the temporary and now empty workbooks.
This would be quite non-effective approach, but might appear most easy if you already mastered built-in DevEx exporter.

Otherwise those links above have a lot of references to purchase some exporter or create one.